# reading hex values from fstream into int

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a text file which has one hex value in each line. Something like

```
80000000
08000000
0a000000
```

Now i am writing a c++ code to read this directly. SOmething like

```
fstream f(filename, ios::in);

while(!f.eof)
{
    int x;
    char ch;
    f>>std::hex>>x>>ch;  // The intention of having ch is to read the '\n'
}
```

Now this is not working as expected. While some of the numbers are getting populated properly, the ch logic is flawed. Can anybody tell me the right way of doing it. 
I basicaly need to populate an array with the int equivalent.

Comment: The operator >> ignores whitespace (that includes '\n') so the ch is reading the first character of the next word ('0') and '('0')

Comment: btw, eof is not a field, but a method, so the expression should be !f.eof()

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("AAPlop");

    unsigned int a;
    while(f >> std::hex >> a)   /// Notice how the loop is done.
    {
        std::cout << "I("<<a<<")\n";
    }
}
```

Note: I had to change the type of `a` to `unsigned int` because it was overflowing an `int` and thus causing the loop to fail.

```
80000000:
```

As a hex value this sets the top bit of a 32 bit value. Which on my system overflows an int (sizeof(int) == 4 on my system). This sets the stream into a bad state and no further reading works. In the OP loop this will result in an infinite loop as EOF is never set; in the loop above it will never enter the main body and the code will exit.

Answer (score 1):

fstream::operator>> will ignore whitespace so you don't have to concern yourself with eating the newline.

Answer (score 0):

... and the way to change it is to use `noskipws`: `f >> std::noskipws;` will set no skipping of whitespace until you use `std::skipws` manipulator.

But why do you want to read the `'\n'`? To make sure that there is one number per line? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, extracting whitespace manually in the code you've shown is unnecessary. However, if you do come across a need for this in the future, you can do so with the [`std::ws`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/io_flags#manipulators_defined_in_istream) manipulator.