# Reading in HEX number from file

Tags: c++

This has me pretty bothered as I should be able to do it but when I read in the hex number and assign it to an unsigned int when I print it out I get a different number.  Any advice would be great.  Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
fstream myfile;
myfile.open("test.text");
unsigned int tester;
string test;
myfile >> hex >> tester;
cout << tester;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How different? Like not hex anymore? Will `cout << hex << tester;` help?

Comment: I never understood people who write answers in comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555849/reading-hex-values-from-fstream-into-int

Comment: Your code works. Probably your filename is not `test.text` and it reads *bricks* from memory.

Comment: @Tomalak: LOL, it was a joke... you know... ["when you see it, you will shit bricks!"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shit%20bricks) :) See [wild pointers on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you don't get a "different number".

I bet you get the same value, but in decimal representation.

You're already extracting a hex-representation value (`myfile >> hex >> tester`); now insert one, too (`cout << hex << tester`)!

Comment: I've did that before and just tried it now.  What I get on the screen is cccccccc.  My number is 0041f7a0 in my file and during debugging the variable has 3435973836 in it.

Comment: cccccccc is uninitialzed value in debug mode. You don't check that the file open is successful. Perhaps you don't actually read a value from the file?

Comment: (Sometimes, depending on your implementation and runtime, etc)

Comment: I agree. Maybe you meant `test.txt`. Perform error checking. And, before it comes up: [yes, `"0x123"` is a valid hex input to `istream`](http://codepad.org/hEKAZFM4).

Comment: Tomalak your right!  Oh man I want to beat my head against the wall!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This works for hex value in string format to int**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("test.txt");
    string fromFile;
    unsigned int tester;

    myfile >> fromFile;
    istringstream iss(fromFile);
    iss >> hex >> tester;
    cout << tester;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This works int to hex

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
fstream myfile;
myfile.open("test.txt");
unsigned int tester;
string test;
myfile >> tester;
cout << hex << tester;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Also check your filename. In my file It had a 54 written on it than output was 36 in hex.

Comment: He's reading "a hex number". Your code is parsing in decimal.

Comment: "int to hex" makes no sense. `int` is a numeric value, regardless of the human-readable representation in which you decide to print it. [edit: OK, you _did_ say "string" too.] And you're *still* not reading a number from a hex representation, and printing it to a hex representation.