# c++ convert string to hex

Tags: c++, string, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ convert hex string to signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer)

I allready searched on google but didn't find any help.
So heres my problem:
I have strings that allready contains hex code e.g.: string s1 = "5f0066"
and i want to convert this string to hex.
I need to compare the string with hex code i've read in a binary file.

(Just need the basic idea how to convert the string)
5f
Best regards and thanks.

Edit: Got the binary file info in the format of unsigned char. SO its 0x5f...
WOuld like to have teh string in the same format

Comment: What does mean "want to convert this string to hex" if they already are in hex?

Comment: `strtol()` from `<cstdlib>`? Just guessing, your question is not very clear.

Comment: In case you read these strings from file (specifically, from `std::ifstream`), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555849/reading-hex-values-from-fstream-into-int) may be a better answer than the duplicate question posted above.

Answer (score 19):

Use [`std:stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) as (in C++11 only):

```
std::string s = "5f0066";
int num = std::stoi(s, 0, 16);
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/Qbgcl)

Comment: An unsigned integer such as 0xffeeddcc will probably throw std::out_of_range. Fix: use std::stoul

Comment: If the string is too long, it won't convert to a correct number (int can't hold so much). I don't really like this answer.

Answer (score 14):

Use **[stringstream](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/95826-stringstream-tutorial/)** and **[std::hex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/hex/)**

```
std::stringstream str;
std::string s1 = "5f0066";
str << s1;
int value;
str >> std::hex >> value;
```

Comment: I got the folowing:
    1500-030: (I) INFORMATION: std::num_get<char,std::istreambuf_iterator<char,std::char_traits<char> > >::_Getffld(char *, istreambuf_iterator<char,std::char_traits<char> > &, istreambuf_iterator<char,std::char_traits<char> > &, const locale &): Additional optimization may be attained by recompiling and specifying MAXMEM option with a value greater than 8192.

Answer (score 7):

`strtol(str, NULL, 16)` or `strtoul(str, NULL, 16)` should do what you need.

[strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/)
[strtoul](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/)