# How to extract hex value from a string in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code :

```
string num = "4D"; // means 77 in dec
```

Is there away to extract that number as it is and put it in a new variable? I need to get the decimal equivalent of this hex number

Comment: `std::istringstream` and `std::hex` should do what you want.

Comment: ```std::stoi("4D", 0, 16);``` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608878/c-convert-string-to-hex