# How do I copy data from a file into an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I am writing a program which requires me to read a 128 bit block of data from a file into an array. How do I go about doing this?

The code I have been using is below, but I don't think it works.

```
ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    inFile.open("datain.txt");
    outFile.open("dataout.txt");

    for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
   {
    inFile >> tempin[i];
    }

    inFile.close();
```

Comment: Usually streams have a read()function where you can specify exactly how many bytes to read into the buffer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555849/reading-hex-values-from-fstream-into-int

Comment: Did you not just ask this? I remember backing a comment about reading as binary on the same question.

Comment: Could you show example input?

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the file to a string, and parse it to convert the hexadecimal digits to bytes.